# Same Url but different web pages using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a 2 pages, first is login.php, second is index.php.

My current function is when the user is not logged in yet, index.php `includes login.php` to appear, and if the user is already logged in index.php will show it's page.

Here is how it works:

```
index.php

if(!$user->loggedin()) {
   include 'login.php';
} else {
   'show the page of index.php';
}
```

I do this because, I want my url to the 2 pages like this `www.mysite.com/`.

The problem is, index.php loads a little bit slower because it includes another page. How can I fix this ? Is there any alternative to do it? 2 pages in 1 url ?

Comment: if user login ready, it's will show content of `index.php` and no include `login.php` why you said it's load slow because include other page? or have other page else ?

Comment: It loads slower because, if the user is not logged in yet, it will include login.php. I compare it to my register.php, and its slower 1s more or less.

Comment: if user not login yet, it's will run to load `login.php` and no content of `index.php`

Comment: yes. you are right